# after_initialize for MongoMapper?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper, activemodel

ActiveRecord has `after_initialize`, but ActiveModel does not. MongoMapper is built on ActiveModel.

Is there a way to create an `after_initialize` callback for MongoMapper?

Comment: https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper/issues/59 MongoMapper has (AFAIK) been abandoned. What specific use do you have for an `after_initialize` hook?

Comment: When creating a user, I want to downcase the email after initializing it.

Comment: Why not use a `before_validation` hook for that?